# UTF-8 Characters in Apache Access Log ✔

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, encoding, utf-8, charset

**The issue**

I'm using PHP's `apache_note()` to log variables from web requests to a CustomLog format. However, try as I might, Apache doesn't want to log UTF-8 characters the way I'd like.

In PHP, I have `apache_note('some_value', '✔');` which corresponds to the VHost config which looks like this:

`LogFormat "%{some_value}n" custom_format
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log custom_format`

However, Apache ends up logging the literal version like this:

```
\xe2\x9c\x94
```

**What I've tried**

- Checked the values of both `LANG` and `LC_ALL` and they are both set to `en_US.UTF-8`
- Updated `/etc/apache2/envvars` to use `/etc/default/locale` by default
- Using mod_charset_lite I have set `CharsetSourceEnc  UTF8` and
  `CharsetDefault    UTF8` in the Apache config for the site (I know this is for content in/out)
- Checked that /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset has set `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`
- Tried sending the logging output through a piped log to another program - its `\xe2\x9c\x94` by the time it gets there, so it certainly seems like its something to do with the Apache process itself.
- Read through [the Apache logs docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

Ultimately, I want that access log to show something like:

`✔`

but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get there.

**Other information**

- Apache version 2.4.10
- Debian 8.4

**Update**

Per Esa's suggestion, I modified the `LogFormat` directive:

`LogFormat "%{some_value}n ✔" custom_format`

And I get the following:

`\xe2\x9c\x94 ✔`

Which is interesting, because it suggests Apache's willingness to log UTF-8. However, I'm still not convinced that the issue has anything to do with PHP passing non UTF-8 values.

```
  apache_note('some_value', '✔');
  $value = apache_note('some_value');
  print_r($value);
```

in PHP still prints out

✔

I will try re-compiling Apache next to see fi it helps, but I do need this in production which may be dicey.

Comment: Have you tried to add the character directly to the `LogFormat` directive? This way you can narrow the problem down to either PHP `apache_note()` or Apache logging related. Apache uses the current locale and everything in your configuration looks consistent. Maybe the escaping happens within `apache_note()` function or before it gets to variable `%{some_value}`.

Comment: @EsaJokinen : Great suggestion. Just tried modifying the `LogFormat` directive to `LogFormat "%{some_value}n ✔" custom_format` and what do you know, it correctly logs a ✔. I'll update the information in the main question.

Answer (score 1):

[Escaped logging is a feature](https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html#Apache)

> Starting from 2.0.49, the Apache logging API escapes everything that
>   goes to error_log, therefore if you're annoyed by this feature during
>   the development phase (as your error messages will be all messed up)
>   you can disable the escaping during the Apache build time:
>
> ```
> % CFLAGS="-DAP_UNSAFE_ERROR_LOG_UNESCAPED" ./configure ...
> ```
>
> Do not use that CFLAGS in production unless you know what you are
>   doing.

Comment: This is an excellent finding, but not an exhaustive answer: OP is talking about access log instead of error log.

Comment: @EsaJokinen yeah well for those they'll have to monkey patch out a whole bunch of `ap_escape_*` calls mostly in `mod_log_config.c` and possibly other places, in which case the "Do not use ... in production" line doubly applies.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that it gets escaped in ap_escape_logitem. Have a look at the following code. It uses a macro called TEST_CHAR to determine what needs escaped, but output is basically ASCII

https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/5ed78e19a21609f7097f9049b2fe6db8e471f810/server/util.c